# How do I manipulate a data.frame to arrive at this desired result? Lag somehow?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to manipulate a data table in a difficult to describe manner.  My gut tells me it’s some kind of lag but I'm not sure - so I'll illustrate.

I can do this easily in excel but my data set is too large for excel to handle efficiently.

Initial Data:

```
Column1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Column2 <- c(201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201803, 201804, 201805, 201803, 201804)
Column3 <- c("Active", "Active", "Active", "Closed", "Active", "Active", "CO", "Active", "BK")
Column4 <- c(100, 97, 95, 0, 50, 45, 45, 100, 90)
(dat <- dplyr::tibble(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 A        201801 Active      100
2 A        201802 Active       97
3 A        201803 Active       95
4 A        201804 Closed        0
5 B        201803 Active       50
6 B        201804 Active       45
7 B        201805 CO           45
8 C        201803 Active      100
9 C        201804 BK           90
```

Desired output:

```
Col1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C")
Col2 <- c(201010, 201802, 201803, 201003, 201804, 201803)
Col3 <- c(201802, 201803, 201804, 201804, 201805, 201804)
Col4 <- c("Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active")
Col5 <- c("Active", "Active", "Closed", "Active", "CO", "BK")
Col6 <- c(100, 97, 95, 50, 45, 100)
Col7 <- c(97, 95, 0, 45, 45, 90)
(dat_desired <- dplyr::tibble(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7))

# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Col1    Col2   Col3 Col4   Col5    Col6  Col7
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     201001 201802 Active Active   100    97
2 A     201802 201803 Active Active    97    95
3 A     201803 201804 Active Closed    95     0
4 B     201003 201804 Active Active    50    45
5 B     201804 201805 Active CO        45    45
6 C     201803 201804 Active BK       100    90
```

Incidentally, based on some of the suggestions below, I have tried the following (but am generating the errors below):

```
library(zoo)

R <- read_excel("H:/R Programs/R_Data.xlsx")

Column1 = as.vector(R[,1])
Column2 = as.vector(R[,2])
Column3 = as.vector(R[,3])
Column4 = as.vector(R[,4])
Column5 = as.vector(R[,5])

(dat <- dplyr::tibble(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5))

# A tibble: 415,533 x 5
Column1$Loan_Key Column2$File_Run_Date Column3$Status Column4$Days Column5$Bal
<dbl>                 <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
1         11111111              20180201 ACTIVE                  -19      24472.
2         11111111              20180301 ACTIVE                  -19      24264.
3         11111111              20180401 ACTIVE                  -19      23991.
4         11111111              20180501 BK                      -49      23350.
5         11111111              20180601 BK                      -19      23488.
6         11111111              20180701 BK                      -19      23169.
7         11111111              20180801 BK                      -19      23008.
8         11111111              20180901 BK                      -19      22693.
9         11111111              20181001 BK                      -19      22378.
10        11111111              20181101 BK                      -19      22192.

# ... with 415,523 more rows

(data.frame(rollapply(data = dat, 2, c)) %>% filter(X1 == X2) %>% 
    select(-X2) %>% setNames(paste0("Col", 1:9)))

Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found
```

Comment: You shouldn't attach images of data here, because they are quite unhelpful for anybody trying to reproduce your issue. Plain text is preferable because anybody can cut and paste that without worries.

Comment: Ok - thanks.  I’ll paste text in a couple mins.  Appreciate the guidance so I can ask more effective questions.

Comment: Still waiting for reproducible data. The image link seems dead as well.

Comment: Can you explain how you want the data grouped? Is it by Column1 and sequential Column2s (months?)?

Comment: It’s difficult to articulate.  I am trying to show transitions from one state to another.  So, as an example, A is Active status on 201801 and remains Active on 201802.  Similarly, A starts as Active on 201802 and remains Active on 201803.  Continuing, A is Active on 201803 but moves to Closed on 201804.  B is Active on 201802 and stays in Active on 201803.  Then, B starts in Active on 201803 and transitions to CO on 201804.  Does that help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `rollapply()` function from zoo:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

rollapply(data = dat, 2, c) %>% # returns a character matrix
  data.frame() %>%
  colwise(type.convert, as.is = T)(.) %>% # Guesses column classes
  filter(X1 == X2) %>% # only reports the same Column1 values
  select(-X2) %>%
  setNames(paste0("Col", 1:7)) %>%
  as_tibble() # optional

# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Col1    Col2   Col3 Col4   Col5    Col6  Col7
  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 A     201801 201802 Active Active   100    97
2 A     201802 201803 Active Active    97    95
3 A     201803 201804 Active Closed    95     0
4 B     201803 201804 Active Active    50    45
5 B     201804 201805 Active CO        45    45
6 C     201803 201804 Active BK       100    90
```

This assumes the rows are already in the correct order.

Comment: Wow - so cool!  Thanks Paul.  I can’t wait to try it when I get to work.  Thanks!

Comment: This one seems to be producing an error - first, it didn't recognize the colwise function - should it use plyr (rather than dplyr?)  I am also seeing the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : the first argument must be of mode character

Comment: Yes, it needs `plyr`, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this basically just a self-join (i.e. a `left_join` of `dat` with `dat` on `"Column1"`)?

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    left_join(dat, by = c("Column1")) %>%
    filter(Column2.y - Column2.x == 1) %>%
    select(
        Col1 = Column1,
        Col2 = Column2.x, Col3 = Column2.y,
        Col4 = Column3.x, Col5 = Column3.y,
        Col6 = Column4.x, Col7 = Column4.y)
## A tibble: 6 x 7
#  Col1    Col2   Col3 Col4   Col5    Col6  Col7
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     201801 201802 Active Active   100    97
#2 A     201802 201803 Active Active    97    95
#3 A     201803 201804 Active Closed    95     0
#4 B     201803 201804 Active Active    50    45
#5 B     201804 201805 Active CO        45    45
#6 C     201803 201804 Active BK       100    90
```

Comment: I think this is the right approach. You could also do it as a single join if you create a column first for the `-1` lagged match - `dat %>% mutate(Col2m1 = Column2 - 1) %>% inner_join(dat, by=c("Column1","Col2m1"="Column2"))` for instance.

Comment: Thanks - I’ll try this too.  I think it makes sense - will know shortly and will report back.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This seems like it should work but I am getting an error:
Error: std::bad_alloc

Assuming that means the data set is too large?  I am using a 64 bit windows pc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul (and to you others) I think this gets me to where I need to be.  it took me quite a while to implement what ended up being 1 line.... :(

```
R <- read_excel("H:/R Programs/R_Data.xlsx")
x=data.frame(rollapply(data = R, 2, c)) #THIS WAS THE KEY STEP
Transition = x %>% filter(as.character(X1)==as.character(X2)) %>% select(-X2) #THIS AS.CHARACTER ALSO CAME INTO PLAY DUE TO DIFFERENT FACTOR LEVELS (FOR SOME REASON)
write_xlsx(x=Transition, path="C:/Transition_Matrix_Data.xlsx")
```